# How to make vscode format SCSS calc function properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, stylelint, scss-lint

I have an SCSS file that contains a calc() function.
When i use a calc function without spaces around the operator like so  `calc(var(--primary-color-h)+5)` the transpiled CSS result doesn't work. Only when i set spaces around the operator does it work; like this  `calc(var(--primary-color-h) + 5)`
How would i instruct VSCODE to created spaces around the operator upon save.
I have prettier, scss Formatter and StyleLint installed. But neither seems to fix it.
tnx,
RDG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stylelint and the following two rules:

- [function-calc-no-unspaced-operator](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/function-calc-no-unspaced-operator/)
- [function-whitespace-after](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/rules/list/function-whitespace-after/)

These will flag the lack of space before and after the `+` operator, respectively. See [this demo](https://stylelint.io/demo#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-v4e4GgEzhBmMjpgaEHIolyMEwC4hw8HaBGLvYNRDKsKgQDe9agV0DFaCUF6MusXDGDRC5tu+oRAUQP5QCxGQ-CoNx6pwEA9OKgkhm+u71OJJoQCofJln4tT5DhgSUvOqlEbU1owOYzh9tEfB8q4tZsaZKFvqa5rRmEkQxHELmEV0jKUVgvDYIyjiSZwckAQ+3nPr5yH+VMgVMsF9BhRFFF5MOMVPi+fl0aomVUbwhRmlWsV5Xg1K0rRRKeDVpLmOSJlVbKXTMrMimDC4vQaNKsoKjSthKhcKrCbMTDxiOMDRN2LW1Se4R8uVuXxQtb5ENgfAXpKPwhJonZUkS9hmpQkGaIm9iLrY9UNfYrT1gUAAKiynZiNHVQ1XQ4HWiH2ANiqTGNJ76cZgz5Ksc2PDALoUkdQ1TEQ0RIGw0rXcSCNdA9MAFPDX1dNqEQuPov4mN8vAqIGd4-ITxNo21UxmJQszBK43z5jKmPyujjXNXj+O+GTywKUpGj-Vzg01SN3jAxt-hgx+64EIy8T2Nw0TLFdwmg3h1MwU5PxIELlCq8ghDI6jMFbEEc1ayD8u6zUbLGjwCww4wbT5drDtBLxKIQNwO4zVDRvk6bSMo-TJ6E5F2nQWk0L1uDww0FDaQwzw830TAVp22+MfXHHU0J3We3B3UhvG+H5uR3nFQF9wOnF4nZezRX0Ow1nZsWwBzDOEcqcV3XBPwrHTfbCXSc1qXHeZ9XPdW-GNtD0owkx0scjxy3rNtz2pNh6Mvg15bfeEAPtur9Ho8b1vM-T0noea4f3eR4v5jLz2w9TOvZqb83d8G1nnDZ+EdUZf3sPxPYHYyz7W3KbZg0Bli+QKpAloWhywq2furJ+KCA6uz4K0VOfRzD8lNnqA04Dui9X8IxDgacM7ANagjI+Pcv43VlPdLQj0jw4gZs6RgzN-A9lmA2cWX1ZZ3RAGSOevCuYBUKC4bs-hIA9CNFAfqEtAbKlwaLfwdkHL3x+HUHSsB5610vm+Dq-x3IrA4LQwee906d35htY+Ucaq3Rqpw7hLjJGP14FYrqNjChsNpPwwRrMREcwGjzKY0jGEoE+l9QW5MRbUNCW+YxTQZLWx+GneEYiGqS1pNLWwEj2p-C6meRgF5awYHJmtJJFQAB6JBsQXgAF5ynaTQDpAAGGgABOOUAAqAQtAen9KGXKIQAgRkABJQmeLCaeVwlNLrPwAKJaDNIcBs+BKnMBQNU1AABHcYlA2AoEVjATAEAUDpxQFmNISA0gYJMlo0aKDDkAjehwOpDTfFdFaZM7pnSBnDLGRM8F0zZkLKWRw1Z+gkAbLwPYbZuz2YHM6kc4JVybl3Iebc55rz3mFIuKU7mwl1TQk7I8I02xDH7yfmi98OccHUs3BqMsLyppMqcTI1loD3Fqi5bSnlo8-b8SDrvSuB8hVuJoKfc+K8Co0u3HCZ42QpV4IeEy-xZjLbjw-iZNVYqNUxx1YHfWM8BUJOzrnCxorrjcq1JK3JDifisHQeqzsNEACMZqXXirdVqmg3F0zQStXOBVrCnUQnNXSmONQKRvAnP0QO5htrGl+eaYEKlXLOq3HS6VO8Q5VxAYq5VjBPWUN9WWUt+qK2xtfsavJqrOXBo1Y2wBdqu49kdUG4tZZ7H0OcbIrxL8wHxu8Mst82NcYToFsgY2G4u2HRnZOpmLNhHs3JbScpKz4nzSaZO-xaTxQZIqFk2Ab8TWaqyPu0anyZYFRdP0SM6ZvRU3ORAb4NEWGvzsmKAITJFK9VgBzN90DYQqNYGW9uBrK0L2rbWmd7YSwlvAzxQBSGW1Go9RfaDmGG3YZtUnPtpsB0cpPMWWcDxvXJ0hhXGifTiP0b1srLu2CTboZAHRultYKQaAIYyaK5c943q7sKpV-ca1EeEgJssQnxSie5EyqTVH2UU0Ix22jMGHg3kIDQX9-7DUiqLAZnk9l-24ebYjNxlC+DjA3AOGAe0-1wJAUvU1wk6iwA0F5vAAAmAqy5VyBmilTAFSCgVTBBZ0sFvSIWjPGTQSZKW4WLM3RjZJSL1ldwxSlfZ4W1y3IJVgIlTyYAvLeVxp90ggYFRcPGfkvTlihBinydiUxGOjpY-EQNwlGNQxayQvgg3gtseGw2Gpl4-A3h+D2meeGHNxoKic+b15bzLYoww-t2nKGbdFAt28NyyVYOfDRt8x2ryLb1k7PokkQoUjMJ7BKG3ZsXhO9ttEf4ROuHU4AzTz9qO8c++eLb93oTxh+E2VKTb5VrfMRDubP3ocMrh6dZsFNe37fM0dr7JmLl0I2MosjPZZXMt4-h3ucm0Oo4vOc5YpOWZwZwyt+zgGCM+YZzNyHzPLmDzZ2R-l+PQeHb4wxCGHBt3+Avh94SDEA7WYMQbHr9EYwbHHoMHNEATAwRYmdVuCv1pgUcMwdOvAXBICFFNDpHWCdS4t1bpV2g3ZgA2PceIAAWAqcgXfCxqBG7s2wHeLALYlE6r0PIXdZTxyheKBjO2e27N7GuHC636448XTCz1VvpwphGc6KgLp4Xn5dcvIl7s5uI2J9hj1xY2quuDl7a9FJfWUgqyViqYRKIwNILIaaJyzBgACGmGTZK04O8aRVUp+H74P-08PXaI5ZVMMHlCe-z-qUwJfWPlg4-IzTXPG-Jfd7n67Bfe+h-E7-fhbnFmkqX4CVFegC-YtLrfAl3pSWpmQrSwy1hTmWy3RhLy6F6GRVRSmCKz2SgHwCihQG3x4EJUeRJTqyQEwU7ypRPGQICUUjSDqCPzXxp2R2nQvyCldhUUII-ARzx3HVpy3xfw3BUEgigEPBFhoKPxqFHGPwzzwNqBNA-0oEaWOhAB-y6SAIAOhWS2APhRy3AN6zWRRUKx2WK3gKaCQJf1QOJRq1JXq3bwpSa1n0oOtzJzSQvEp3LSR0fyYNMOF3J1UWPyAQOxn1wOYL6xl09VYwoJSldkexdhe3dnezNwCmYNChgHClCBdRJgMPjyu3BxML8JCnSmiLfxUwBzE2cJB1ZU3z4wEIiKiO6iyn6DiKmAT3yPCNSOKOoQUmtVgQ3VZUkkcGkjsOSPDTYDKjKLVgSK331BWGzRNBj1sQGFTXCHYP6F2kj2737ymlMwfxAGaNaL4yWmUUwO416L412kzGzFzEoGaG6JAAqIKm2MaBFycKsMQy5ynTpzPnkz0zfFOPMPZ2cNW0fzvXbU-i2KIBczOMcPgzFwYLPzcMeJ+PbRZk8JTjmh8OEm2ICNTwYGCNBBSCVCkBACkCAA).

This rules are turned on the [SCSS standard config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stylelint-config-standard-scss), which you can extend in your Stylelint configuration object:

```
{
  "extends": "stylelint-config-standard-scss"
}
```

> How would i instruct VSCODE to created spaces around the operator upon save

You can use the [`editor.codeActionsOnSave`](https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint#editorcodeactionsonsave) option from the [official Visual Studio Code extension for Stylelint](https://github.com/stylelint/vscode-stylelint). And the following to your VS Code settings file:

```
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.stylelint": true
  }
```